# Но что-то часто я стал его "непонимать"

Tags: орфография, не-с-глаголом

Хочется написать "не" с глаголом слитно. Совсем нельзя?

Вот такой подчеркнуто стилизованный под разговорную речь диалог.
*-Ты его не понял, он хотел сказать [то-то и то-то].

- Хорошо, если так. Но что-то часто я стал его **"непонимать"**.*

Рука тянется написать слитно - вопреки всем правилам. Или все-таки есть какое-то соображение, оправдывающее хотя бы отчасти слитное написание? Уж больно режет глаз сочетание "стал не + инфинитив".

"Стал" можно заменить на "начал", но это скорее уж смысл изменит, нежели развеет сомнения.

Comment: Соображения вряд ли есть. Но об этом писал д.ф.н. Михаил Эпштейн. http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=1.90

Comment: @Серж Спасибо, интересно, хотя кажется, видел я его раньше - не впечатлился. В любом случае Э. немного о другом... Он орфограмму предлагает новую (весьма спорную), а я о обосновании в рамках действующей.

Comment: *Рука тянется написать слитно* — я не вижу других причин для этого, кроме того, что "непонимать" в данном примере имеет утвердительный смысл. Э. говорит в точности об этом.

Comment: @grizzly  *я не вижу других причин для этого* - причина, как сказал, в неуклюжести (как минимум) конструкции "стал/начал не + инфинитив". Это частный вопрос - по сравнению с глобальным подходом Э. Ну еще то, что после "не" здесь невозможно сделать паузу - даже интонационную. Возможно, это как-то взаимосвязано, но до глобальности Э явно не дотягивает.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно одновременно соблюсти нормы, то для обозначения условности написанного можно поместить нужный вариант в кавычки. Я бы при этом выбрал вариант раздельного написания, поскольку в сочетании *стал "не понимать"* экспрессивности достаточно, кавычки вполне извиняют стилистический изыск, а орфография не отвлекает от содержания своей нестандартностью. Но и слитный вариант от кавычек стал бы корректным.

В статье Анны А. Зализняк, СЕМАНТИКА КАВЫЧЕК

http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/zaliznyak_anna-07.htm

приводится и такая их функция:

> 6.3. Кавычками маркируется новое слово, созданное говорящим ad hoc в данном речевом (письменном) акте. Для бытовой письменной речи
>   характерно употребление слов, не существующих в русском словаре, но
>   потенциально возможных.

Comment: Кавычки-то я поставил, не вопрос. Вопрос в слитном/раздельном написании. Кавычки свет на его решение не проливают никак.